# PHP video stream not working when using If(empty(variable)){set variable; redirect}

Tags: php, android, internet-explorer

What my PHP script do?
 It streams video to the browser using fread(). I covered all scenarios in android/iPhone, desktop... it is working unless I add the below script.

Once I add the below piece of code at the start... stream doesn't work in Internet Explorer and Android phone. Internet explorer(Desktop) asking to save video instead of streaming(I don't want this to happen)

But works well in Google chrome(desktop), iPhone(safari, chrome) even with the below script.

```
if(empty($executed))
{
     $executed = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], 'XYZ');

     if(empty($executed))
     {
            header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com");
     }
}
```

If I remove the code then it works fine everywhere.

By putting the above code my intention is to redirect if I don't find the text in the Client URL.

my html:

```
<object data="../myPHP/?id=54654654"></object>
```

Please Help.

I have tried sessions also.. again the same result as above.

Thanks,
Prakash R

Answer (score 0):

You must check `strpos` result is `===false`, not empty, because position can be 0, and `empty(0)` is true. `strpos` return false, if needle not found.

Example:

```
if(empty($executed))
{
     $executed = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], 'XYZ');

     if($executed === false)
     {
        header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com");
     }
}
```